# Refactor if/else statement - Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, refactoring

I know there has to be a better way to write this. I try not to use if/else if possible, or at least cut them down, but I'm still a noob with Ruby so some refactoring help would be much appreciated.

```
def super_fizzbuzz(array)

array.map {|x|
    if x % 15 == 0
        "FizzBuzz"
    elsif x % 3 == 0
        "Fizz"
    elsif x % 5 == 0
        "Buzz"
    else x
    end}

end
```

Comment: You in an interview?

Comment: @DaveNewton - No, just doing a challenge at home.

Comment: You should ask this kind of question on codereview.stackexchange.com.  See this:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56927/fizzbuzz-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[spoilers]

There are [several ways](http://rubyquiz.com/quiz126.html) to do this classic problem... This way has no ifs/elses

```
 (1..100).each do |x|
 m3 = x.modulo(3) == 0
 m5 = x.modulo(5) == 0
 puts case
   when (m3 and m5) then 'FizzBuzz'
   when m3 then 'Fizz'
   when m5 then 'Buzz'
   else x
 end
end
```

OR, if you prefer the if statements and small code blocks, this is a good refactoring of what you have

```
(1..100).each{|i|
  x = ''
  x += 'Fizz' if i%3==0
  x += 'Buzz' if i%5==0
  puts(x.empty? ? i : x);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
def super_fizzbuzz(array)
  array.map do |x|
    case 
    when x % 15 == 0 then 'FizzBuzz'
    when x % 3  == 0 then 'Fizz'
    when x % 5  == 0 then 'Buzz'
    else x
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do something like

```
array.map do |x|
  [FizzBuzz, Fizz, Default].map do |fizzer|
    fizzer.new(x).get
  end.compact.first
end

class FizzBuzz
  attr_reader :x
  private :x

  def initialize(x)
    @x = x
  end

  def get
    'FizzBuzz' if x % 15
  end
end

class Fizz
  attr_reader :x
  private :x

  def initialize(x)
    @x = x
  end

  def get
    'FizzBuzz' if x % 3
  end
end

Default = Struct(:get)
```

...

That way you will split responsabilities and have each class responsible for only one thing.